# How can I Run hibernate application with datasource in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, sql-server-2012, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

*Hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyStatus-process</property>
```

*web.xml*

```
<resource-ref>
            <description>DB Connection</description>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyStatus-process</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

*HibernateUtil class*

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");   //configuration settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            log.error("--- Exception while creating the initial session factory creation ---", ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

I was not able to run with above configuration. Can any one give some ideas on it.
I was able to run with below configuration:

*Working Hibernate Configuration:*

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/DB_INSTANCE_NAME;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">sa1234</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
```

Comment: The question needs clarification. Do you want to connect to database in your application or create connection for IDE (by [defining the data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-data-sources.html) in IDE) to execute the queries in IDE sql console?

Comment: I want to connect database for my application. No need of executing in  IDE sql console. For your information, I want my service to run with above configuration in Intellij IDE with maven DEBUG configuration(cmd: tomcat7:run)

Comment: I was able to run with hibernate properties which I updated now in the description(Refer: Working configuration)

Comment: It is better to add the clarification about the initial problem in question description and post the answer with the information that helped you. Thanks.